# Kotlin - How to create the function "mutableListOf()"

Tags: kotlin, immutablelist

Is there a way to create my own dynamic List with out using mutableListOf()? Cause in c++ we use pointers, while in Kotlin i think we cant :(

I searched in diferents sites and i only found how to use the function, not how was it created :(

Comment: Why don't you want to use `mutableListOf`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to know how the function is implemented, click on the "source" link in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html). But your question doesn't really make sense. What do pointers have to do with anything? Please [edit] your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: You cannot use pointer arithmetic in Kotlin (or other JVM languages), but you don't really have to. What are you trying to achieve here? What would you do if you could use pointers directly?

Answer (score 2):

`mutableListOf()` is just a shorthand to create an instance of `MutableList`, optionally passing some arguments that will be placed in the list upon creation. The 0-arg version of the function is extremely simple and creates an `ArrayList`:

```kotlin
fun <T> mutableListOf(): MutableList<T> = ArrayList()
```

You can of course just create instances of lists yourself, by simply instantiating some implementation of the `MutableList` interface. For instance, on the JVM, you can create an instance of `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` by simply calling their constructor:

```kotlin
val myList = ArrayList<String>() // creates a new empty ArrayList<String>
```

You can also define your own list implementation by creating a class that implements the `MutableList` interface:

```kotlin
class MyList<T> : MutableList<T> {

    // implement MutableList methods here
}
```

And then you would create instances of it by calling its constructor:

```kotlin
val myList = MyList<String>()
```

> Cause in c++ we use pointers, while in Kotlin i think we cant :(

You cannot use pointer arithmetic in Kotlin (or other JVM languages), but you don't really have to.